# Show that if $\mathbb{Z_n^*}$ has an element of order d, then it has at least $\phi(d)$ elements of order d. (Proof Critique)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Let $a \in \mathbb{Z_n^*}$, and $O(a) = d$. (Where O(x) denotes the order of x in $\mathbb{Z_n^*}$ and $\phi(n)$ is the Euler Totient function).
We have that $$O(a^s) = \frac{d}{gcd(s,d)}$$ which is equal to $d$ if $gcd(s,d) =1$. Taking $S =\mathbb{Z_d^*}$, we see that $S$ contains exactly $\phi(d)$ elements. Thus for any $s_i \in S$ 
$$O(a^{s_i}) = d$$

We will now show that there are at least $\phi(d)$ of these elements in $\mathbb{Z_n^*}$. Suppose that 
$$a^{s_i} \equiv a^{s_j} \mod n \quad i \neq j,\quad j<i $$ Then we must have that $d|s_i -s_j$, which is impossible since $s_i,s_j < d$ by definition. It follows that $a^{s_i}$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z_n^*}$ for each $s_i$ with order $d$, and there are (at least) $\phi(d)$ unique such elements.